# Two-Dimensional Gaussian integral in complex coordinates.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, mathematical-physics, gaussian-integral

> (4) A two-dimensional Gaussian integral in complex coordinates:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &\frac{1}{\pi} \int \exp \left(-\mu \alpha^{2}-\nu \alpha^{* 2}-z^{*} \alpha+z \alpha^{*}-|\alpha|^{2}\right) \mathrm{d}^{2} \alpha \\
> &\quad=\frac{1}{\tau} \exp \left[-\left(\mu z^{2}+\nu z^{* 2}+z z^{*}\right) / \tau^{2}\right], \quad \tau=\sqrt{1-4 \mu \nu}, \quad \mu+\nu<1 .
> \end{aligned}
> $$

[(Transcribed from picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeJRk.png)

Can anyone suggest some text reference where I can get to learn about the result and about Two-dimensional Gaussian integral in complex coordinates in general? Any Mathematical Physics text reference is preferred. I am having problems dealing with them in my study of Quantum Optics.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: Please write equations in latex formatting instead of attaching images, this will help your question get better answers and avoid it being closed.

Comment: Difficult to understand the connection with Fourier Transform. Is there a connection with quaternions like here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.1014.pdf ?

Comment: I am not aware of the connection with quaternions, so I cannot comment on that. The kernel of the transformation here is $${e^{z\alpha^{*}-z^{*}\alpha}}$$ which transforms a function $$Q({\alpha},\alpha^{*})$$ to, lets say, $$P(z,z^{*})$$ which is the expression on the right side of the equation.

Comment: I understand. I have never seen this. As it deals with a function of 2 complex variables, the usual notation for the differential element should have been $dz d\overline{z}$. It is a detail but it is interesting to know it if you are looking into maths books about "functions of several complex variables" like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Fourier-Analysis-Several-Variables-Mathematics/dp/0486449750)

Comment: I too haven't seen this before. Can you give the source for this?

Comment: Its from this book Quantum Optics by Girish Saran Agarwal page-22. This page is available in the preview here. https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Quantum_Optics.html?id=InUgAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&redir_esc=y

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/678465/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It follows from my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/679132/2451) that OP's [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) becomes
   $$ \begin{align} I~:=~&\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \!  \frac{\mathrm{d}{\rm Re}\alpha \wedge \mathrm{d}{\rm Im}\alpha}{\pi}~ 
   \exp\left\{-\mu \alpha^{2}-\nu \alpha^{* 2}-z^{*} \alpha+z \alpha^{*}-|\alpha|^{2}\right\}\cr
   ~=~&\int_{\mathbb{C}} \!  \frac{\mathrm{d}\alpha^{\ast} \wedge \mathrm{d}\alpha}{2\pi i}~ 
   \exp\left\{ -\frac{1}{2}A^TSA +Z^TA\right\}\cr
   ~=~&\sqrt{\frac{-1}{\det(S)}}\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}Z^TS^{-1}Z \right\}\cr
   ~=~&\frac{1}{\tau} \exp \left\{-\frac{\mu z^2+\nu z^{* 2}+z z^{*}}{\tau^2}\right\}.
   \end{align}$$
2. Here we have defined
   $$ \begin{align} 
   A~:=~&\begin{pmatrix} \alpha   \cr \alpha^{\ast} \end{pmatrix}, \cr
   Z~:=~&\begin{pmatrix} -z^{\ast}   \cr z \end{pmatrix}, \cr
   J~:=~&\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \cr 1 & -i \end{pmatrix}, \cr 
   S~:=~&\begin{pmatrix} 2\mu & 1 \cr 1 & 2\nu \end{pmatrix}, \cr
   \tau^2~:=~&-\det(S), \cr
   S^{-1}~=~&\frac{1}{\tau^2}\begin{pmatrix} -2\nu & 1 \cr 1 & -2\mu \end{pmatrix}, 
   \end{align}$$
3. Moreover, the Gaussian integral $I$ is convergent if ${\rm Re}(J^TSJ)>0$ is [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_definiteness).